# Find latest occurrence of value in multiple columns and return value in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

```
home_team <- c('Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team B', 'Team F')
away_team <- c('Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team A', 'Team F', 'Team A')
home_team_score_pre <- c(300, 150, 600, 800, 50, 450)
away_team_score_pre <- c(550, 340, 100, 208, 412, 18)
winning_team <- c('Team A', 'Team C', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team F', 'Team F')
res <- c(16, 25, 11, 4, 22, 9) 
home_team_score_change <- c(16, -25, 11, 4, -22, 9) 
away_team_score_change <- c(-16, 25, -11, -4, 22, -9)
home_team_score_post <- c(316, 125, 611, 804, 28, 459)
away_team_score_post <- c(534, 365, 89, 204, 434, 9)
```

Output:

```
  home_team away_team home_team_score_pre away_team_score_pre winning_team res home_team_score_change away_team_score_change
1    Team A    Team B                 300                 550       Team A  16                     16                    -16
2    Team B    Team C                 150                 340       Team C  25                    -25                     25
3    Team C    Team D                 600                 100       Team C  11                     11                    -11
4    Team D    Team A                 800                 208       Team D   4                      4                     -4
5    Team B    Team F                  50                 412       Team F  22                    -22                     22
6    Team F    Team A                 450                  18       Team F   9                      9                     -9
  home_team_score_post away_team_score_post
1                  316                  534
2                  125                  365
3                  611                   89
4                  804                  204
5                   28                  434
6                  459                    9
```

Each team starts with a score before a game is played (`home_team_score_pre` and `away_team_score_pre`).

After a game is played, an adjusted score is the result (`res`) and this is either added or subtracted from both teams depending if they won or lost the game. E.g. line 1 home team is `Team A` who wins, `res` is 16, so `Team A` has 16 added to their score, while `Team B` loses and has 16 subtracted from their score. The result overall is a score post game (`home_team_score_post` and `away_team_score_post`).

What I am trying to do is to update the `home_team_score_pre` and `away_team_score_pre` by looking for the previous game played by each team, then inputting the value on either `home_team_score_post` or `away_team_score_post`).

So, for example, if the next two lines are:

```
  home_team away_team home_team_score_pre away_team_score_pre
1    Team C    Team B  
2    Team A    Team F
```

Then I would want to look for the last game played by 'Team C' (line 3) and enter the `home_score_post` (611) into the `home_team_score_pre column`.

Similarly, for the last game played by `Team B` (line 5) and enter the `home_score_post` (28) into the `home_team_score_pre column`.

The values can come from either column as it is the value for the game the team last played, so they could have been either the home team or away team.

Also, if the team is playing it's first game (hence no previous value), I would like to enter a default value of 100.

So, final output would be:

```
home_team away_team home_team_score_pre away_team_score_pre winning_team res home_team_score_change away_team_score_change
1    Team A    Team B                 100                100       Team A  16                     16                    -16
2    Team B    Team C                 84                 100       Team C  25                    -25                     25
3    Team C    Team D                 125                100       Team C  11                     11                    -11
4    Team D    Team A                 89                 116       Team D   4                      4                     -4
5    Team B    Team F                 59                 100       Team F  22                    -22                     22
6    Team F    Team A                 122                112       Team F   9                      9                     -9
7    Team C    Team B                 136                37        Team B  12                      49                      131
8    Team B    Team F                 49                 131       Team F  10                      0                      0
  home_team_score_post away_team_score_post
1                  116                  84
2                  59                   125
3                  136                  89
4                  93                   112
5                  37                   122
6                  131                  103
7                  124                  49
8                  39                   141
```

Comment: What is the final output that you want? include it in your question

Comment: Also your question topic talks of finding the previous values, yet the way you expressed seems to find the latest value and not the previous value. Which is which?

Comment: apologies, I have added final output as an example. Yes, latest value is what I am looking for. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update - 2022-10-05

If you have starting data (`df`) that look like this:

```
  home_team away_team winning_team res
1    Team A    Team B       Team A  16
2    Team B    Team C       Team C  25
3    Team C    Team D       Team C  11
4    Team D    Team A       Team D   4
5    Team B    Team F       Team F  22
6    Team F    Team A       Team F   9
```

you can convert it using the following approach

1. load library, and add a column indicating the game number

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, game:=.I]
```

2. Melt long, generate indicator columns for whether or not this is the first game for a team, and whether or not there is a win, and set the initial values (i.e. 100 for first game), and post score for those first games

```
df_long = melt(df, id=c("game", "res", "winning_team")) %>% 
  .[, fgame:=min(game)==game, value] %>% 
  .[fgame==1, score_pre:= 100] %>% 
  .[,win:=winning_team == value] %>% 
  .[, score_post:= fifelse(win,res,-res)+score_pre] %>% 
  .[order(value,game)]
```

3. Use a for loop to fill in the previous score and the post scores for all the other appearances for a team

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_long)) {
  if(df_long[i,is.na(score_pre)]) {
    df_long[i,score_pre:=df_long[i-1,score_post]]
    df_long[i,score_post:=df_long[i,score_pre] + fifelse(df_long[i,win],res,-res)]
  }
}
```

4. Cast the data back to wide format, and rename columns

```
dcast(df_long, game+res+winning_team~variable, value.var = c("score_pre", "score_post","value")) %>% 
  .[, .(home_team = value_home_team, away_team=value_away_team, 
        home_team_score_pre = score_pre_home_team,
        away_team_score_pre = score_pre_away_team,
        winning_team, res,
        home_team_score_post = score_post_home_team,
        away_team_score_post = score_post_away_team)]
```

Output:

```
   home_team away_team home_team_score_pre away_team_score_pre winning_team   res home_team_score_post away_team_score_post
      <char>    <char>               <num>               <num>       <char> <num>                <num>                <num>
1:    Team A    Team B                 100                 100       Team A    16                  116                   84
2:    Team B    Team C                  84                 100       Team C    25                   59                  125
3:    Team C    Team D                 125                 100       Team C    11                  136                   89
4:    Team D    Team A                  89                 116       Team D     4                   93                  112
5:    Team B    Team F                  59                 100       Team F    22                   37                  122
6:    Team F    Team A                 122                 112       Team F     9                  131                  103
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(home_team = c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C", "Team D", 
"Team B", "Team F"), away_team = c("Team B", "Team C", "Team D", 
"Team A", "Team F", "Team A"), winning_team = c("Team A", "Team C", 
"Team C", "Team D", "Team F", "Team F"), res = c(16, 25, 11, 
4, 22, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

### Previous Solution

You can use a helper function as below:

```
# Helper Function return row
prepare_next_row <- function(df, home, away) {
  r = data.table(home_team = home, away_team=away)
  lrh = last(df[home_team==home | away_team == home])
  lra = last(df[home_team==away | away_team == away])
  r[, home_team_score_pre:=fifelse(lrh$home_team==home,lrh$home_team_score_post, lrh$away_team_score_post)]
  r[, away_team_score_pre:=fifelse(lra$home_team==away,lra$home_team_score_post, lra$away_team_score_post)]
  r[]
}
```

Now, when you want a new row(s), you simply call it, along with `rbind()`

```
rbind(
  df, 
  prepare_next_row(df, "Team C", "Team B"),
  prepare_next_row(df, "Team A", "Team F"),
  fill=TRUE
)
```

Output:

```
   home_team away_team home_team_score_pre away_team_score_pre winning_team   res home_team_score_change away_team_score_change home_team_score_post away_team_score_post
      <char>    <char>               <num>               <num>       <char> <num>                  <num>                  <num>                <num>                <num>
1:    Team A    Team B                 300                 550       Team A    16                     16                    -16                  316                  534
2:    Team B    Team C                 150                 340       Team C    25                    -25                     25                  125                  365
3:    Team C    Team D                 600                 100       Team C    11                     11                    -11                  611                   89
4:    Team D    Team A                 800                 208       Team D     4                      4                     -4                  804                  204
5:    Team B    Team F                  50                 412       Team F    22                    -22                     22                   28                  434
6:    Team F    Team A                 450                  18       Team F     9                      9                     -9                  459                    9
7:    Team C    Team B                 611                  28         <NA>    NA                     NA                     NA                   NA                   NA
8:    Team A    Team F                   9                 459         <NA>    NA                     NA                     NA                   NA                   NA
```

Comment: that is great. How about if I already have the data, and I don't wish to add a new row? Rather just update based on what I have? Apologies if I did not make this clear in the initial post.

Comment: okay, I didn't understand - I've now changed my solution substantially.

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I need. Apologies for the late reply, I have been sick. I have accepted your answer.